# Show Image From URL in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

How can I convert Image URL to any showable type, I want to show it with my CustomAdapter just like "Category_Name" and "Category_Description" as in the following code ;

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(result); // Result is my JSON
                asd = new String[3][jsonResponse.length()];
                rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject js = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
asd[0][i]= js.getString("Category_Name"); // Fetch Category Name
asd[1][i]= js.getString("Category_Description"); // Fetch Category Description
asd[2][i]= js.getString("Image"); // Fetch Image URL

RowItem item = new RowItem(R.drawable.abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo, asd[0][i], asd[1][i]); 
// I delivered asd[0][i] as a title and asd[1][0] as a post content..
rowItems.add(item);
                }
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How Can I use Fetched Image URL and show it just like title , post content.

Custom Adapter ;

```
private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDesc;
    }
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc()); // RowItem Setter Getter Method
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle()); 
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: check [this](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134). it is well described in details

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the image and set it to the imageView

To download and set the image:

```
public void downloadImageFromUrl(ImageView iv, String path){
    InputStream in =null;
        Bitmap bmp=null;
        int responseCode = -1;
        try{
        URL url = new URL(path);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.connect();
                responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    //download the image
                    in = con.getInputStream();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    in.close();
                    if(bmp!=null)
                           iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }

    }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Exception",e.printStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is my return value ? Where and How do I define this method and take back value to onpostexecute(), your answer is so poor.

Comment: This is just the basic answer which you are missing on downloading the image from the server. FYI, this method takes an input of imageView reference so if you call this function it will set image for you. Also, if you are using List view try using a Lazy loader.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) .It helped me a lot in parsing image and making my custom adapter.Hope it will also help you.

Comment: It didn't help me.It is so complicated What i needed to do is just convert the existing Urls and send them to my CustomAdapter.Thanks anyway